# Generate Admin area ( CRUD ) on Play Framework

Tags: java, web-applications, frameworks, playframework

I'm following the [Official tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/crud) for creating a administration area. I did the first step correctly but when i extend my controller class to CRUD i got an error (Crud not found on the project) + `Access denied` when I access to http://localhost:9000/admin/. This is what I did:

1. Enable the CRUD module for the application
   In the /conf/application.conf file, enable the CRUD module by adding this line:

   `module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud`

   Import default CRUD routes
2. In the conf/routes file, import the default module routes by adding this line:

   `*      /admin              module:crud`
3. Create the Users controller

   ```
   package controllers;

   public class Users extends CRUD {

   }
   ```
4. Restarted play & eclipse

Any suggestion to get the admin area work please ?

Comment: Could you specify which version of play you're using? And did you well created the User model class and not only the controller?

Comment: Why can you get an access denied? Have you included the secure-module?

Comment: it's supposed to work without secure-module. The play version is 1.1 and yes i created user model

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running this command again

```
play eclipsify myApp
```

Comment: When you enable the CRUD module you're basically adding it as a dependency to your application, so Play knows where to find it.  However, as Play warns you, Eclipse doesn't update what it knows about your project's dependencies unless you add them through Eclipse.  `eclipsify` remakes your project's Eclipse config files so that it can now see the CRUD files.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the tip, play eclipsify made the trick but before, i had to resolve dependencies as they are now in the dependencies.yml file:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - play -> crud
```

Just launch "play dependencies myApp" and then eclipsify. Reload your project in Eclipse and it works.

Tested in latest (1.2.3)

Fabien

Comment: Or just 
`require:
   - play
   - crud
`

Answer (score 3):

This could be caused by several issues. Let me outline steps to validate your setup:

1. Controller name must be plural (controllers/Users.java)
2. **Make sure** you have model (models/User.java)
3. Controller must extend CRUD
4. run play dependencies
5. run play eclipsify and re-import project (just in case)
6. Annotate model with @Entity
7. Routes for /admin **must be before** /{controller.action} ...
8. application.conf must contain following line:

   > ```
   > module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud</li>
   > ```

*Comments:*

- Used Play framework version 1.2.3 does not require to have crud in dependencies.yml

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem but there can be a problem with your route definitions.
Please check your conf/routes file
the entry `.*    /admin   module:crud`   seems a little bit strange to me
when you start your play! server are there any logging messages indicating wrong route definitions?
e.g. `Invalid route definition : .* /admin module:crud`
I think the definition should look something like this `*    /admin    module:crud`

Comment: i put (.) before * /admin module:crud cause stackoveflow recognize (*) as <li>...</li> but in the route file it's like this * /admin module:crud

Comment: @Mooh - but when in "code mode" it doesn't - I removed the dot and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was this:

The Controller objects must be plural (end in **s**)!

> The controller’s class name has to be the model class name with a
>   final ‘s’.

e.g. if you have *User.java* model object, the controller object extending CRUD must be *User**s**.java*

I was running Play 1.2.3 on Windows 7 and this took me a while to figure out, hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the tutorial, the route file is as follows

```
# Import CRUD routes
*      /admin              module:crud
```

You should also check that the CRUD module exists, by going to

```
play/modules/crud/
```

If it does not exist, I would suggest downloading the latest version of Play.

Comment: I have the latest version of play and the module exists in play/modules/crud/

Comment: i put (.) before * /admin module:crud cause stackoveflow recognize (*) as <li>...</li>

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally wrote my entity under the `model` package instead of `models`.